# How to prevent creases and imprints while hanging clothing to dry to prevent ironing?

Tags: clothing, laundry

Wet clothing has to dry. My only option to get it dry is to hang it. (no dryer)

There are a few options to do this, which both get the job done:

- **hang the items of clothing on the line** as they are
- use **pegs**

The problem with these is that they introduce creases and/or imprints from the pegs that look awkward and make ironing the clothing necessary.

Note that for formal attire ironing can hardly be circumvented, which is perfectly fine. But I don't see the point in ironing the bulk of t-shirts that I wear every day, especially if it is mostly because of the creases introduced while drying.

Even if hanging a wet t-shirt perfectly without any creases, the line still produces a very distinguishable imprint. Sometimes that's still visible even after ironing.

At the moment, I concoct an experiment with a coat hanger. It's not an ideal one because it's made out of wood and not too thick. It's still thicker than a wire hanger though or the clothesline for that matter. I guess **a plastic coat hanger with thicker shoulders** would be ideal. If that means putting all t-shirts on coat hangers, so be it. That saves me from folding them.

Any ideas on that? The ideal solution would be to make ironing obsolete for these kinds of every day items of clothing like t-shirts. **Is there any problem with that?** Say for example, should clothing be ironed for some other reason than removing creases?

**What other solutions aside from coat hangers are there?**

Answer (score 2):

They sell those close hanging racks for that very purpose with multiple bars that you just lay the item over the bar. I do this all the time for items that cannot be dried and they don't leave any marks. They sell drying racks at any multi-purpose store like Target. Mine is made of smooth coated aluminum and has about 8 bars, with each able to fit one garment. It folds up to flat and weighs only a couple lbs at most!

If you have no drier you'd probably need a couple.

For light blouses and materials that dry super fast, I sometimes just go right to a foam lined hanger.

The iron or not to iron question is one of preference. I only iron stuff that is wrinkled or something like a cotton dress shirt that looks crisper with a fresh pass with the steam setting. But no, there is no reason you should otherwise.